How can I seal between steel framing and a wavy floor slab?
My shop leaks in multiple places because the concrete guy did a horrible job so the steel foundation of the shop is not airtight sealed to the concrete. Trying to figure out the best material to use around the outside to keep water from leaking in. Was thinking of using outdoor polymer like DAP AMP then doing concrete like quikrete over that. Thanks for your advise!

Any steel should've had a sill foam under it, right? Product recommendations are off topic here, but more importantly I'm unclear about your intentions in general. Why would you involve concrete for a crack sealing endeavor? Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then see if you can revise to clarify your question.

FYI, a seal between the framing and the concrete isn't how water should be managed. Your siding (or its drainage membrane) should lap over that joint, making it mostly a matter of stopping airflow for energy efficiency. Water should never encounter your framing.

Get us some photos, please.
